# Set array into table view?

Tags: iphone

Here is what my XML looks like (I'm calling XML using JSON)

```
<shishir>   
    <english>    
        <0>a</0>   
        <1>aa</1>    
        <2>aaa</2>    
        <3>aaaa</3>
        <4>aaaaaa</4>    
        <5>aaaaaaa</5>
    </english> 
</shishir>
```

Now what I want is to put this value in an array, and then I want to set this array into a table view.

But I have no idea how can I do it. How can I set this array in a table view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have valid XML, it's easy to parse it using [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can then create a `UITableViewController` subclass and present the data in the array quite easily.

These two guides should be of help:

- [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html)
- [Table View Programming Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

Comment: What if  i want  to retrive values in between
<0>shishir</0>
<1>shishir2</1>

 tags

i want output as shishir shishir2

how can i do this?

Comment: can u explain parser:foundcharacter, l'll bit more.

thanks n regard
shishir